# Tire pressure warning when pressure is ok

Tags: tires, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

The low tire pressure warning light has recently come (and stayed) on in my 2009 Jeep Wrangler. The pressure in all 5 tires (spare also) is at the proper level. Any suggestions as to what the problem may be and how to remedy it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely cause: One of the sensors in a tire is faulty - and often it is the spare, as it doesn't get looked at very often.

Take it along to your dealer and get them to check the sensors are all working and powered.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem in my Hyundai Sonata 2009 Limited where the Bluetooth signal from my iPad interferes with the TPMS operation.  In this case, the TPMS fault light on the dashboard cluster illuminates as opposed to the low tire pressure warning light adjacent to it .... but it's easy to mistakenly confuse the two.  Happened the first time on a trip and did cause a bit of concern until I researched it on the Internet and realized that others had encountered the same problem.  This may or may not be the cause of your anomaly but I thought it was worth a mention.